# Appropriate way to configure contrasts and interactions in GLM likelihood ratio test

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, interaction, contrasts

I have a pretty large experiment where we are looking for differences in gene expression in RNA sequencing experiments. We are using EdgeR's GLM functionality, and then using contrasts to look for differences between groups. We are unclear on the most reasonable way to form powerful, informative contrasts that take into account interactions.

The general setup is this:
We sample R  unique regions (here let's just take R = 2), C unique cell types (again C =2 for simplicity), from N patients from four unique conditions (two diseases each with two levels). Here's a table that describes this with the minimum possible N (in reality we have many replicates of each group so that this makes more sense).

| Individual | Region | Cell Type | Disease A | Disease B | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | - | - | A.A.-.- |
| 1 | A | B | - | - | A.B.-.- |
| 1 | B | A | - | - | B.A.-.- |
| 1 | B | B | - | - | B.B.-.- |
| 2 | A | A | + | - | A.A.+.- |
| 2 | A | B | + | - | A.B.+.- |
| 2 | B | A | + | - | B.A.+.- |
| 2 | B | B | + | - | B.B.+.- |
| 3 | A | A | - | + | A.A.-.+ |
| 3 | A | B | - | + | A.B.-.+ |
| 3 | B | A | - | + | B.A.-.+ |
| 3 | B | B | - | + | B.B.-.+ |
| 4 | A | A | + | + | A.A.+.+ |
| 4 | A | B | + | + | A.B.+.+ |
| 4 | B | A | + | + | B.A.+.+ |
| 4 | B | B | + | + | B.B.+.+ |

- The simplest question one can ask is "What's the difference between +- and -- within a region x cell type pair?" We address this with the contrast (for instance) `(A.A.+.-) - (A.A.-.-)`
- From here, we get a little lost.  One question we would like to address is "Within a fixed celltype/ region, what is the effect of disease A regardless of disease B?".
  We have tried a few different approaches and are unclear what is appropriate. The first is to construct `(A.A.+.-) - (A.A.-.-)` and `(A.A.+.+)-(A.A.-.+)` and take the intersection of the significance sets. However, I get the feeling that 1) the intersection is not a smooth operation, so things that are "almost significant" in one will be excluded, which is not desirable and 2) If there are interactions between disease A and disease B, or if the effect of disease B is quite large, then significance can easily be obscured.
  Our next attempt at answering this question is to take the average effect of disease A:
  `1/2((A.A.+.-) - (A.A.-.-) + (A.A.+.+)-(A.A.-.+))`, which is more of a "soft intersection", but does not deal with any interactions in disease B status. Does including a term like
  `1/2((A.A.+.-) - (A.A.-.-) + (A.A.+.+)-(A.A.-.+)) - 1/2((A.A.-.+) - (A.A.-.-) + (A.A.+.+)-(A.A.+.-))` account for those interactions? We are very concerned that we are overspecifying here.
- If this larger contrast w/ extra interactions is appropriate, can a similar approach be applied to ask questions of the form "Given a cell type, what genes are different in disease A region A that are not different in disease A region B?"? This contrast formula would be `(effect of disease A in region A) - (effect of disease A in region B)`, or:
  `(1/2((A.A.+.-) - (A.A.-.-) + (A.A.+.+)-(A.A.-.+)) - 1/2((A.A.-.+) - (A.A.-.-) + (A.A.+.+)-(A.A.+.-))) - (1/2((B.A.+.-) - (B.A.-.-) + (B.A.+.+)-(B.A.-.+)) - 1/2((B.A.-.+) - (B.A.-.-) + (B.A.+.+)-(B.A.+.-)))`
- In contrast (ha), would the sum of the two terms be the answer to "what genes are expressed in both regions in disease A?", e.g.,
  `(1/2((A.A.+.-) - (A.A.-.-) + (A.A.+.+)-(A.A.-.+)) - 1/2((A.A.-.+) - (A.A.-.-) + (A.A.+.+)-(A.A.+.-))) + (1/2((B.A.+.-) - (B.A.-.-) + (B.A.+.+)-(B.A.-.+)) - 1/2((B.A.-.+) - (B.A.-.-) + (B.A.+.+)-(B.A.+.-)))`
- In general, can I just continue this line of thought for further specification to cell types?

Can you recommend any resources that tackle these more complex multifactorial experiments?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I think I understand the general issues here, but I don't see where the "GLM likelihood ratio test" noted in the title appears. Please say something about that, preferably by editing the question itself. (Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.) I don't have time for an answer yet, but in the meantime read [this Bioconductor vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/RNAseq123/inst/doc/designmatrices.html), which seems on point. Also, try adding the `bioinformatics` tag to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, I added the mention of a GLM - we are fitting a GLM using EdgeR and performing a LRT on the contrasted model coefficients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sections 6 and 7 of the [Bioconductor vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/workflows/vignettes/RNAseq123/inst/doc/designmatrices.html) on creating design matrices for gene expression experiments are helpful here, as is Section 3.3.1 of the [edgeR User's Guide](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/edgeR/inst/doc/edgeRUsersGuide.pdf). A few issues stand out to me in your question.

First, and most fundamental: if there is an interaction between Diseases A and B with respect to gene expression, then there is no longer a reliable measure of "the effect of disease A regardless of disease B." The interaction means that the effect of disease A on gene expression *depends on* whether disease B is also present. That's the case whether you're talking about a simple linear regression model or a massive single-cell RNAseq study. Unless you can document that an additive model without an interaction is adequate (see below), you can't do what you seek. With any substantial interaction you have to take all factors into account.

The issue with "overspecification" when there are interactions then is whether there are enough cases having each combination of predictors to get reliable results. In your situation, with all regions and cell types evidently available for all individuals, that comes down to having on the order of 10 or so individuals in each of the 4 combinations of Diseases A and B.

Second, you are handling your multi-factor study by combining the factors into a single `Group` predictor. I have used that approach myself with simpler multi-factor experiments analyzed with `limma`. It's recommended in Section 3.3.1 of the edgeR User's Guide ("Defining each treatment combination as a group") and is how Section 7.2 of the design-matrix vignette ("Conversion to a single factor") handles a situation similar to yours (two tissues and two cell types within each tissue).

With that setup I'd recommend using a design matrix for the model (e.g., for a call to `glmQLFit()` in `edgeR`) without an intercept (`design <- model.matrix(~0+Group)`), and then carefully constructing contrasts with informative names that represent all the comparisons of interest. As best as I can tell, that is pretty much what you are doing (although without informative names yet for the contrasts). You have 16 levels of `Group`, which (as you certainly have come to recognize) requires a lot of care and concentration to accomplish without error.

One particular type of contrast can evaluate whether an additive model (i.e., without interaction) is adequate: a contrast that should equal 0 if there is *no* interaction, for example between diseases A and B.

Third, I think you might be ignoring a strength of the models provided by the `limma` and `edgeR` packages. You say that you might "take the intersection of the significance sets" after you set up two separate sets of contrasts. But with the single model provided by a function like `glmQLFit()` you can evaluate any combination of conditions (e.g., a contrast of contrasts) that you want without having to restrict yourself to "significance sets" first. It might take some thinking through with your colleagues to get the contrasts specified properly, but finding a useful overall contrast and holding off on defining "significance sets" (at least until the end) is probably a good idea. Some methods for evaluating gene-set significance work best with a full ranked list of genes rather than "significance sets."

A final warning: as you are dealing with multiple contrasts, don't forget to deal with corrections for the multiple comparisons if you intend to report "statistical significance" of the results.

Comment: on multiple comparison correct: We were intending to apply FDR to the pvalues after the contrasts. e.g., for contrasts A,B,C, with average effect (A+B+C)/3, we would apply FDR to those pvalues. Are you suggesting that we need to do something different to accomodate the fact that there are three contrasts? 

If we were using FWER, say Bonferonni, then we'd multiply the adjusted pvalues by 3*(N Genes). But how would that work with FDR?

Comment: @jay I think you are OK, if I understand your comment correctly. In general, you can use the `p.adjust()` function in R to do any of several multiple-comparison corrections, including FDR, that works on a list of _p_ values.